# Should a wrapper be tested in addition to the code it wraps?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Should a unit test test the wrapper of a method, the method itself, or both?
Here's an example of what I mean:

```
public static class Helper
{
  public static bool DoAThing() {
  //do stuff...
  }
}

[TestClass]
public class HelperTests
{
   [TestMethod]
   public void TestDoAThing()
   {
      Assert.AreEqual(true, Helpers.DoAThing());
   }
}

public class APIMethodsController : ApiController
{
    public bool DoAThingWrapper()
    {
        return Helpers.DoAThing();
    }
}
```

So should there be a test for DoAThingWrapper() in addition to TestDoAThing()?

I'm inclined to think that for a simple case like this, that there should only be TestDoAThing(). But how much more complexity should there be in the wrapper before you add a test for DoAThingWrapper()?

Answer (score 3):

> Should a unit test the wrapper of a method, the method itself, or
>   both?

Unit test should test public interface of the type you are testing. If both methods are public, then you should test both of them. Otherwise, test only public wrapper.

Note that you define `DoAThing()` as an instance method of the static class, which is not allowed in C#. Also you are calling it as an instance method of `APIMethodsController` or `ApiController` class, though it defined in `Helper` class.

Though there are some ways to unit-test code that depends on static (e.g. TypeMock or Moles), I recommend you depend on abstractions instead. That will make your code easy to unit-test by mocking its dependencies. E.g. instead of using `Helper.DoAThing()` which is hard to make returning value required for your test, you can create a wrapper which calls static members:

```
public class HelperWrapper : IHelper
{
    public bool DoAThing() => Helper.DoAThing();
}
```

Now you can easily mock `IHelper` and test decorator which use it to make sure `DoAThing` of dependency is called. I use the same technique for `ConfigurationManager` class.

```
var helper = new Mock<IHelper>();
helper.Setup(h => h.DoAThing()).Returns(false);
var controller = new APIMethodsController(helper.Object); // inject dependency
var result = controller.DoAThingWrapper();
result.Should().BeFalse(); // ensure you pass through value from helper
```

Comment: Fixed the code as you mention.